# Acessing HTML buttons having the same names and values by vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to access Some HTML buttons. I am using vb.net 2008 platform to click these buttons programatically . Problem is that the all 17 buttons are without id and have the same name type and value and are in a same form . So plz guide me how to click each button indivisually . Here is the HTML code of the these buttons.

Answer (score 0):

lets say that the you got a webbrowser control 
And The Html Is:

```
"<button id=namee>Click</button><button id=namee>Click</button><button id=namee>Click</button>"
```

you can change the id's of the butoons + click them:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate("")
Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    Application.DoEvents()
Loop
WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = "<button id=namee>Click</button><button id=namee>Click</button><button id=namee>Click</button>"
For i = 1 To 3
    WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml = Replace(WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml, "namee", "n" & i.ToString, , 1)
Next
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("n1").InvokeMember("click")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("n2").InvokeMember("click")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("n3").InvokeMember("click")
```

Comment: when you use replace on the html of the page, you can replace the <button -- with -- <button id=name & i.tostring after you replaced it you can click the button by the id that you give to him

Answer (score 0):

there is another way:

```
Dim Elems As HtmlElementCollection
Dim WebOC As WebBrowser = WebBrowser1
Elems = WebOC.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
For Each elem As HtmlElement In Elems
    elem.InvokeMember("click")
Next
```